# Databinding in C# with views and how to update them

Tags: c#, mysql, data-binding, view

I'm currently updating a software in c# which accesses a MySQL database and allows to modify, add, and delete values from the database. Currently, it's user data (i.e. user name, first and last name, email address and so on). This is currently working pretty fine using databinding, bound controls, a binding navigator and all that stuff.

I now want to extend the software and add several new items to it. Unfortunately, I cannot change the currently existing database tables. I have to create new ones. For example, in addition to the table "users", I now create a table "userdetails" with some additional information. For brevity, let's say it's birthdate and sex.

The new table has a 1:1 relationship with the users table and I can easily retrieve a combined listing of all users and their extended properties.
Also with C# this is working pretty fine. But as the query is quite long and complicated, I decided to create a view and bound the controls to that.

I know, one cannot directly update a view. Is there some preferred way to do that in C#?
Can I use the Update method of my TableAdapters?
Do I have to manually write the SQL statements to update the different table my view consists of?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know reason why you don't alter user table to add new column. why do you make new table?
In your case: the best way is alter user table to add new column.

Comment: as already mentioned above, I cannot change the currently existing database tables. Reasons: (1) I do not have the necessary permissions, (2) there are other applications that rely on the current database table layout. Also, the new tables (actually, there are two additional tables) are much more complicated. I just simplified that here.

Comment: must you get data from it? can you create a table as the same it then migrate data from it to new table?

Comment: I need to both get data from the JOINed tables and write data back to all the tables (depending on which values have been changed/added). I do not want to re-create the table with the same data again. I want to avoid dangerous redundancies...